# Bhadanta or Thero

Tags: vipassana, buddha, bodhisattva, early-buddhism, religion

**Thero, Bhadanta, and Venerable..** are words for addressing the old monks, abbots in pagodas and/or temples. I really do not know how they are ranked in Buddhist Sangha. Which title is the highest... and what else?

Comment: Related topic: [What is the appropriate use for the term bhante?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8441/254)

Answer (score 1):

From AccessToInsight's [Glossary of Pali and Buddhist Terms](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/glossary.html):

> samaṇera (samaṇerī):
>   Literally, a small samaṇa; a novice monk
>   (nun) who observes ten precepts and who is a candidate for admission
>   to the order of bhikkhus (bhikkhunīs).
>
> bhikkhu:
>   A Buddhist monk; a man who has given up the householder's
>   life to live a life of heightened virtue (see sīla) in accordance with
>   the Vinaya in general, and the Pātimokkha rules in particular.
>
> thera:
>   "Elder." An honorific title automatically conferred upon a
>   bhikkhu of at least ten years' standing.
>
> mahāthera:
>   "Great elder." An honorific title automatically
>   conferred upon a bhikkhu of at least twenty years' standing.

The female equivalents are samaṇerī, bhikkhuni, theri and mahātheri.

Answer (score 0):

"Venerable" is the English-language translation of *Bhadanta* (or *Bhante*).

As well as [What is the appropriate use for the term bhante?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8441/254) see also [Thero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thero):

> The word literally means "elder". These terms, appearing at the end of a monastic's given name, are used to distinguish those who have at least 10 years since their upasampada (higher ordination).

See also [Ajahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajahn) which appears to mean the same thing ("for Buddhist monks who have passed ten vassa") but in Thai language

Comment: No, Bhante is elder of Aavuso in Vijaya, but Aacariya is a person who has the quality of Aacariya, numbers of memorizing, understanding, and experience more than 10 years. **Thero may not be qualified as Aacariya**.  1 younger vassa calls 1 elder vassa "Bhante".  Qualifications https://unmixedtheravada.blogspot.com/2017/09/how-to-find-right-dhamma-teacher.html

Comment: I think you're saying that -- 1) a younger monk would say "Bhante" to an older monk -- 2) But an older monk would call a younger monk "Avuso" (meaning "friend"), not "Bhante" -- 3)  "Ācariya" (meaning "teacher") depends on whether a monk has memorised and understood etc., not only on seniority -- 4) "Ajahn" is the the Thai word/equivalent for the Pali "Ācariya".

Comment: It's also true, isn't it, that "Bhante" is an appropriate way for any layperson to address any monk?

Comment: 1-4 yes. The last one is yes as well such as in nakulapitasutta https://4sacca.com/?rm.r.14.1...bhante,nakulapit#hl